# Firefox bookmark syncing

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I have a client who uses Firefox as their primary browser. We have enabled folder redirection for their Desktop and Documents folders via GPO and I was hoping to do the same with their Firefox bookmarks as all users have a desktop and access to a Windows 2008 R2 RDS session for remote access and a few have laptops.

I understand there's 2 ways to do this:

1. Enabled Firefox sync. My issue with this is it's all user-driven. They have to sign up for it, manage their password, enable it when using on other machines, etc...
2. Turn on the Appdata\Roaming folder redirection GPO. However, I've read on several different forums that this can cause issues for various applications, most commonly Adobe Reader, so I'd like to avoid it if possible

Does anyone know of another reliable server-side policy to enable syncing of Firefox bookmarks between multiple machines for users in an AD environment?

Thanks for any insight you may have.

Answer (score 0):

You could sync the AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox directory, if that's an option in GPO.

Otherwise, you could place the Firefox profile folder in a directory that gets synchronized (like Documents), instead of in its default location, and then set up Firefox on each computer (using the Profile Manager) so it looks in that directory for its profile.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox